# Как использовать Date или Calendar для изменения значения UITextView через массив?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, дата, calendar

Нужна помощь. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы 2 раза в сутки(каждые 12 часов) String в UITextView, который я беру из готового массива, менялся на следующий String в массиве. Используя Date или функции Calendar я застрял. Предлагайте ваши варианты, заранее спасибо!

```
@IBOutlet var ThisTextView: UITextView!
var array = ["a","b","c","d"]
var lastDate: Date?
var currentDate = Date()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if currentDate == lastDate {
            // Мы ничего не делаем
        } else {
            // Мы меняем string на следующий в массиве используя какую-то функцию/метод здесь  или не здесь, как удобно.    
        }
```

Comment: Откуда берете данные для lastDate? Нужно сравнивать не даты, т.к. это будет очень короткий момент времени.

Comment: Пока не откуда, не могу понять как это все правильно исполнить, не поможете?

Comment: 2 раза  в сутки - в полночь и обед?

Comment: 9:00  и в 17:00 такое время необходимо

Comment: Если пользователь пропускает пару дней, должно проскочить несколько элементов или следующий отобразить?

Comment: Если пропускает - то соответственно пропускает и несколько элементов. Не важно заходит ли он или нет, элементы меняются.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но я не понял с чем именно у Вас проблема: вы не знаете, как можно получить следующее значение массива, или же не знаете как сделать проверку (узнать сейчас час х или нет, что бы изменить значение) ? И еще зависит приложение будет открыто или закрыто в этот момент...

Comment: Я не могу понять как сделать так чтобы менялись элементы через определённое время и отображались при всём этом в textView

Comment: Я сделал все это худо бедно через Timer. Но он не подходит по функциональности, поэтому нужно через Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вариант не сможет отделить вчерашний день от сегодняшнего(если вам это нужно), но благодаря нему можно определить утро, день, вечер и ночь.

```
//Создаем дефолтный грегорианский календарь
  let calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .gregorian)
  //Теперь достаем массив компонентов даты, которые нам нужны и извлекаем из массива ЧАС
  let currentHour: Int = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date()).hour!

  /*Теперь, благодаря тому, что мы знаем текущий час, мы можем определить
  промежутки суток (хоть на каждый час свою функцию пили =) )*/

  //со строгостью или нестрогостью неравенств можешь поиграть в зависимости от того, что ты хочешь 
  if currentHour >= 9 && currentHour < 17  {
     // Этот блок кода исполняется, если сейчас от 9 до 17 часов
     //do something here
  } else {
     //Этот блок кода исполняется вечером, ночью и ранним утром
     //do something here
  }
```

Comment: Ват, это круто, спасибо, я только пытаюсь придумать функцию которая будет перечислять String(из массива) в UITextView, в этом одна из больших проблем)

Comment: Не могли бы вы больше прояснить свою задачу. Может по поводу алгоритма я смогу вам помочь. У вас два промежутка времени и 4 выборки String в массиве, так? Что дальше?

Comment: Есть UITextView в котором что-то написано. Содержания этого TextView должно меняться в 9:00 и в 17:00 каждый день. Вроде и все. Элементов в массиве будет больше чем 4. Я хочу понять как выводить это все на UITextView с помощью кода, который вы написали. Тем более так чтобы String, которые будут использоваться не начинали меняться заново(с первого элемента) когда приложение будет сворачиваться.